# Не переносится static на хостинг TimeWeb через PuTTy. Выдаёт ошибку . Помогите

Tags: django, static

Пытаюсь перенести статику на хостинг .
Настраиваю через PuTTy

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

Ошибка

```
  File "./manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Проверил версию Python, 2.2.17. Пытался обновить Python на сервер пишет

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

Версия Django 3.6

Если надо еще что-то прикрепить, пишите.

Comment: Откуда вы выполняете команду ./manage.py? Попробуйте зайти в каталог с проектом и запустить python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: Я уже в это каталоге и писал

Comment: 1. попробуйте `python manage.py collectstatic`, 2. проверьте виртуальное окружение, есть ли оно или нет. Если есть - то запустите через него. Если нет - попроббуйте создать

Comment: и python обновляется через `apt` / `dnf` / `yum` и другие менеджеры приложений, но не через `pip`